# R memory leak using C external pointers

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to use external pointers in a package, but I ran into an issue where it seemed like the finalizer was not being called and memory leaked.

Below is an extremely contrived example of the issue:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

void finalize(SEXP xp){
  delete static_cast< std::vector<double> *>(R_ExternalPtrAddr(xp));
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP ext_ref_ex() {
  std::vector<double> * x  = new std::vector<double>(1000000);
  SEXP xp = PROTECT(R_MakeExternalPtr(x, R_NilValue, R_NilValue));
  R_RegisterCFinalizer(xp, finalize);
  UNPROTECT(1);
  return xp;
}
```

R side:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("tests.cpp")

# breaks and/or crashes
for(i in 1:10000) {
  z <- ext_ref_ex()
}

# no issue
for(i in 1:10000) {
  z <- ext_ref_ex()
  rm(z)
  gc()
}
```

Running the first loop, R eventually segfaults after enough iterations (issue #1), whereas the expected behavior is that the data should be cleaned up and there should be no segfault.

Issue #2 is that if you interrupt the process and call `gc()`, sometimes the memory will be cleared but usually it won't.  Based on the `htop` report, R uses 60-70% of the memory, even after `rm(list=ls())` and `gc()`.

The second loop experiences no apparent memory issues.

Am I doing something wrong on the C side?  Am I running into a bug?

(R version 3.5.2 ubuntu 18.04 on Windows.)

Comment: There are some functions in Rcpp to provide external pointers. Have you tried that instead?

Answer (score 6):

I can reproduce the issue even when using Rcpp instead of the C API for creating the external pointer and registering the finalizer:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::XPtr< std::vector<double> > ext_ref_ex() {
  std::vector<double> * x  = new std::vector<double>(1000000);
  Rcpp::XPtr< std::vector<double> > xp(x, true) ;
  return xp;
}
```

For me, just including `gc()` in the loop is enough to fix the issue:

```
for (i in 1:10000) {
  z <- ext_ref_ex()
  gc() # crash without this line
}
```

So it seems not an issue with "finalizer not running" but with "garbage collection not running". My interpretation: You are allocating a lot of memory for the `vector` and a little memory for the external pointer. R knows only about the external pointer. So if that goes out of scope, R does not see a reason to run the garbage collection.

Comment: ... and R does so by design -- an external pointer is meant to be "beyond R" and not touched by it.  So if OP allocates there and does not free then it is a simple design error at his/her end.

Comment: @Dirk and Ralf where is the design error, and how would I go about fixing it?  Shouldnt the finalizer "free" the memory when an object goes out of scope?

Comment: As @Ralf tried to explain to you, you can't control when R runs its `gc()`.  So if you want _explicitly controlled behaviour_ design it.  You could use a simple classes with setup and teardown functions.

Comment: @Dirk that doesnt explain issue #2.  If I run gc manually after many iterations, R is still reported as using a large amount of memory.  The memory usage seems to persist even after gc.

Comment: You are argueing with the wrong person. I simply suggest to you that if approach A ("Let's hope and pray R calls us") does not work, I would switch to approach B and add a teardown function ("Let me invalidate my container and free the memory").

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense, but for additional context, registering a finalizer is the approach used by packages creating alt rep objects (e.g. Romain Francois "altrepisode").  Im trying to understand whether I am using the finalizer register function incorrectly, or whether theres a bug?

Comment: @thc The finalizer is called when the R object is deleted, not when it goes out of scope. In your case R sees no need to run the garbage collector and delete the out of scope objects, since they take up very little memory from R's perspective. So the finalizer is correct and there is no bug in R, it just does not behave the way you want it to behave.

Comment: Ralf: that does not explain issue #2, where calling gc manually does not free memory usage.  Sorry, I feel like we are talking past each other.  I will edit the question to hopefully present the issue more clearly.