# Rcpp Objects seem to be destroyed by R's garbage collector

Tags: r, garbage-collection, rcpp

I have a R script that creates Rcpp objects of the same class that are constructed from different underlying data. Then `lapply()` is used to call their method and the data is put into a list.

But after running for a while, it crashes with the following error. To me it seems to be a garbage collector issue.

```
no function to return from, jumping to top level
1: foo(items)
 2: lapply(items) {
 3: FUN(X[[1]], ...)
 4: lapply(1:5, function(i) {
    myRcppModule::bar(item)
 5: FUN(1:4[[2]], ...)
 6: myRcppModule::bar(item)
 7: new(Rcpp::Module("myRcppMod", PACKAGE = "MyRCPP_MOD")$MyRcppModWrapper, list(item)
 8: getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame()))
 9: .getClassFromCache(Class, where)
 10: Rcpp::Module("myRcppMod", PACKAGE = "MyRCPP_MOD")$MyRcppModWrapper
11: .getModulePointer(x)
12: Module(module, mustStart = TRUE)
13: methods::setRefClass(clname, fields = fields, contains = "C++Object", methods = methods, where = where)
14: setClass(Class, contains = superClasses, where = where, ...)
15: is(try(setIs(Class, class2, classDef = classDef, where = where)), "try-error")
16: try(setIs(Class, class2, classDef = classDef, where = where))
17: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {
    call <- conditionCall(e)
    if (!is.null(call)) {
        if (identical(call[[1]], quote(doTryCatch)))
            c
18: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
19: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1]])
20: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
21: setIs(Class, class2, classDef = classDef, where = where)
22: completeExtends(classDef, class2, obj, where = where)
23: .walkClassGraph(ClassDef, "contains", where, attr(ext, "conflicts"))
24: .transitiveExtends(className, by, ext[[i]], exti, strictBy)
25: .combineExtends(byExt, toExt, by, to, strictBy)
26: (function (x)
x$.self$finalize())(<environment>)
27: x$.self$finalize
28: envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv)
```

A snippet looks like the following

```
foo <- function(items) {
    lapply(
        items,
        function(item) {
            data <- lapply(
                1:5,
                function(i) {
                    obj <- myRcppModule::bar(item)
                    obj$getData()
            })
    })
}

while(TRUE) {
    items <- some_vector
    foo(items)
}
```

The script can run much longer without crashing if I call gc() after iteration. This makes me think that I am doing something wrong with the memory. Could a `obj` be freed by `gc` right before `getData()` is called?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
foo <- function(items) {
    lapply(
        items,
        function(item) {
            data <- lapply(
                1:5,
                function(i) {
                    obj <- myRcppModule::bar(item)
                    obj$getData()
            })
            gc(TRUE)
    })
}

while(TRUE) {
    items <- some_vector
    foo(items)
}
```

The Rcpp code for object creation is the following, where the `MyRcppModWrapper` is a normal C++ class.

```
MyRcppModWrapper* createMyRcppMod(SEXP argsexp)
{
    try {
        Rcpp::List args = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::List>(argsexp);
        const auto item = Rcpp::as<std::string>(args["item"]);

        auto obj = new MyRcppModWrapper(item);

        return obj;
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        forward_exception_to_r(e);
    }

    return nullptr;
}

std::array<double> getData(MyRcppModWrapper* self)
{
        try {
            return self->getData();
        } catch (const std::exception& e) {
```

Comment: Yes of course.  When you do `cppFunction("IntegerVector foo(IntegerVector x) { return x+x; }")` the result object, created by Rcpp, is now an R object and managed by R.  _That is how it is meant to be._  You can also create persistent objects, but you would do that differently.  In short, I can't tell what your goal and plan is _but ex ante there is no bug here_ but only features working as planned.

Comment: Are you sure the objects are created correctly in the first place? What sort of memory allocation happens in the module? The question reminds me of https://stackoverflow.com/a/55238976/8416610. BTW, in general please include error messages etc. as text, not as image.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for your response. I do not suspect there is any bug, only want to make the code work correctly. How do I create persistent objects? Or in general, How should I gain control over my Rcpp object in R? Is there any good reading material you would recommend on Rcpp objects' life cycle in R?

Comment: @RalfStubner As a new user of Rcpp, I am not sure. I have updated the post to illustrate how the objects were created. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: My question concerning the memory allocation is not really Rcpp specific but relates to C++ in general. You say that `MyRcppModWrapper` is a normal C++ class. How much data does it own? In which data structure?

Comment: @RalfStubner A lot. At the magnitude of Gigabytes. So you are saying this is similar to the post you shared? The R only knows the pointer while the underlying C++ object owns tons of data.

Comment: Exactly. And since R sees only a small pointer, it does not delete the object when the next object is created. At some point you run out of memory, which the C++ code does not check properly. Instead you have a partially initialised object. By calling `gc()` within the loop, you are forcing R to delete the no longer needed object thereby freeing the C++ allocated memory as well. Note that there is a bit of speculation here since you dir not provide a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R memory leak using C external pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235959/r-memory-leak-using-c-external-pointers)

Comment: @RalfStubner I can work on a minimal reproducible example to verify whether this is actually a duplication. Meanwhile, I am curious what the backtrace actually mean. The error is "no function to return from, jumping to top level". Shouldn't we get a std::bad_alloc from libc++ if memory is used up? Does R mask the exception? Thanks.

Comment: A `std::bad_alloc` exception is only thrown when `new` fails to allocate the memory, not if this happens together with `malloc`.