# Rcpp-Modules: Understanding .finalizer() and why it doesn't get called

Tags: r, scope, garbage-collection, rcpp, environment

I have written a Rcpp-Module named `RMaxima` that spawns a child process when it's constructor is called. My motivation for this question is, that I need an object of this class to be destructed, when R exits a functions execution environment in which it has been allocated and bound to a name.

Here are the important parts of my source file:

```cpp
class RMaxima 
{
  public:
    RMaxima()
    {
        ...

        // spawnes child process by instantiating an object 
        myMaxima = new Maxima(...); 
    }

    ~RMaxima()
    {
        // causes the child process to terminate properly
        delete myMaxima;
    }

    ...

  private:
    Maxima* myMaxima;
};

static void rmaxima_finalizer(RMaxima* ptr)
{
    if (ptr)
    { 
        delete ptr;
    }
}

RCPP_MODULE(Maxima)
{
    class_<RMaxima>("RMaxima")
    .constructor()
    .method(...)
    .finalizer(&rmaxima_finalizer)
    ;
}
```

My understanding of garbage collection in R is that when the interpreter exits an environment the value bindings from this environment are thrown away and R's garbage collection frees up memory for any unbound values.

However, this seems to be different for Rcpp-Modules: If I call and exit a function that creates an instance of my class

```r
foo <- function() {
    m <- new(Rmaxima)
    ...
}
```

then, as expected, m does not appear in the global environment. However, the child process is still running. This means that my class' destructor/ finalizer has not been called. It is called however, when I quit the R session or when I install my corresponding custom package during which loading is tested.

Why? How can I cause it being destructed in a different scope? <strike>"Extending R" (Chambers, 2016) gave me some hint</strike>

> The Rcpp templated type allows conversions to and from "externalptr"
> with computations in the C++ code specialized to the type T of the object referred
> to. Templated code can in fact use 3 parameters: type, storage scope and a final-
> izer to be called when the object pointed to is deleted. The object returned to R
> is in all cases of class and type "externalptr". No information is available about
> the parametrized form.

as to point out that classes are returned as `externalptr` and protected from `gc()`, but I don't see the connection, since object is `typeof(m)`: S4, i.e. a reference class.

Any further hint, where to read about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Rcpp Modules which are in a way an alternative to using things yourself with an external pointer.  Rcpp offers you `Rcpp::XPtr` and those are used by a few packages you could look at.  (My favourite is a quick GitHub search as in [this one across the 'cran' org that mirrors CRAN](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Acran+XPtr&type=code) -- it shows over 1k code hits so some further triage needed.)

And `XPtr` itself seems to have an open issue in as far as *guaranteed* access to the finalizer is concerned; I filed [issue #1108](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/1108) on that last year and plan to revisit this 'soon'.  But despite that issue which may be a corner case, in general this appears to work.  So I would look into `XPtr` and/or the two helper packages for `XPtr` use on CRAN.

Lastly, Rcpp Classes were an extension written and contributed by John. They have not seen too much use though.  Rcpp Modules is fairly widely used, and there too you could look at examples.

Lastly, you could also do something more simple and direct:

- create a class Foo with an empty-ish constructor
- have static pointer to a singleton of the class
- create an `init` method to set up the class and have it hold the memory it needs
- have setter/getter/worker/result methods as needed
- create a `teardown` method to free the memory

and then call init first (maybe from package load), followed by all the work and then ensure the teardown is called. It's a far-from-perfect design (maybe teardown is not called?) but the simplicity gives you a comparison.  And once you have the fragments you can build fancier structures on top.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying terms for me! I edited and specified my question accordingly. I'will look into `Rcpp::XPtr`. However, it seems for what I'm trying to do I can use Rcpp-Modules. Vignette _Rcpp Modules_ says: "A finalizer is a free function that takes a pointer to the target class and return[s] void. ... The finalizer is called automatically when the R object that encapsulates the C++ object is garbage collected.". So why does it not work?

Comment: I just realized the motivation behind your answer (from reading [this post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235959/r-memory-leak-using-c-external-pointers/55238976#55238976)). The point of my misunderstanding was, that an Rcpp module's finalizer is called upon garbage collection *not* upon it's bound R variable going out-of-scope/ `rm()`.

@Dirk: If I write my class the way you propose, how can I "ensure the teardown" is called?

Comment: That is correct, and per _Writing R Extension_ that is also when the finalizers are called.  When I said "ensure the teardown is called" I was referring to a more explicit alternate setup where you control a different structure.  You cannot influence R's internal garbage collector's mechanism (as calling `gc()` more or less "just invites R to think about what it may do" with garbage collection -- as opposed to what `free` or `delete` do.